# Ubuntu software not opening after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: snap-store

I cant open Ubuntu Software , so I have decide to uninstall it and install it again , but when I try to reinstall the Snap Software I got this

```
sudo snap install snap-store
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
       "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-1959167526: wrong fs type, bad
       option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper
       program, or other error.
```

Comment: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd/14767/3 Unistall/reinstall software is mostly a Windows mentality acquired reflex that seldom has any effect in Linux.